# Office 365/Exchange online - I need a list of all devices that connected to EO in last 90 days

Tags: powershell, exchange, microsoft-office-365

So I need to find information as in the topic. I found that get-mobiledevice is quite OK, but it lacks two major informations for me: UPN of user, who used it and the time, when it was used.

I can use get-mobiledevicestatistics to get time of last login, but I don't know how to pipeline the result of get-mobiledevice, which would list me all of the mobile devices, to run the get-mobiledevicestatistics for each of them (and I know, this only resolves the information of mobiles, no desktops).

Neither will get me the UPN as well.

Do you know, how to connect all those commands to get, what I need?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try the following commands:

```
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited 
$report1 = @()
$report2 = @()
Foreach ($mb in $mailboxes) { 
$report2 = Get-MobileDeviceStatistics -Mailbox:$mb.Identity | Select-Object @{label=”User” ; expression={$mb. PrimarySmtpAddress }},DeviceModel,DeviceOS, lastsuccesssync
$report1+=$report2
} 
$report1| Export-csv c:\test\activesync.csv
```

In my testing, it would list all the activesync devices information and user’s UPN like this:
[image]
Here is [a similar case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/add0b115-5207-461d-b0b1-65c2acc897f5/need-to-pull-out-a-active-sync-devices-report?forum=onlineservicesexchange) for details.